# Url routing to lowercase how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed a Web Application on asp.net mvc3 and now i need to make routes, lowercased
Example:

```
 that's what i have:
 http://www.example.com/SubFolder/Category/Index => looks ugly :-)

 that's how i would like it:
 http://www.example.com/subfolder/category/index
```

I have found this post:
http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

I actually need to use the code inside the global.asax in the bottom of the page.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    string lowercaseURL = (Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    if (Regex.IsMatch(lowercaseURL, @"[A-Z]"))
    {
      lowercaseURL = lowercaseURL.ToLower() + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
      Response.AddHeader("Location", lowercaseURL);
      Response.End();
    }
}
```

Now is the question:
When is use it on dev station it's work's perfectly but when i upload it, to production it's not working .

On dev station it's makes only post but on the production it's does two:

```
POST - status: 301 Moved Permanently 
GET  - status: 200 OK
```

and i don't get redirected to the correct route at all.
On the dev station it's works perfectly.

Comment: ASP.NET URL is not case sensitive, what is whole point of redirecting to lower case URL? You are creating overhead of redirect. Also redirect on POST will never work correctly. All you need to do is change your HTML to reflect smaller case URL. And there is no such law that upper cast url is bad, no body looks at it. The only place it matters is at robots.txt which is case sensitive.

Comment: @PKKG, no, SEO is case insensitive, and also if the referring link has different case and redirecting to different case will probably harm SEO considering it as different words if at all it case sensitive.

Comment: @IamStalker : Can you kindly add an answer or suggestion? as you accepted the answer. The accepted answer is removed now unfortunately

Comment: Do you want an answer for my question?

Comment: very interesting problem. any discrepencies between your development web.config and your deploy web.config?

Comment: @IamStalker :  Remember that you accepted an answer for this question. That answer had a link. BUT, was giving 404 error. Unfortunately that answer was present 15 hours ago and is not appearing anymore. If you still have got the details, can you please answer it ?

Comment: Ohhh my god, I don't remember, but I will give you an answer how I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lowercaseURL = (Request.Url.Scheme + 
    "://" +
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority +
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    if (Regex.IsMatch(lowercaseURL, @"[A-Z]"))
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent
        (
             lowercaseURL.ToLower() + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the best way to go about this. Why do it in the application when IIS can take care of it for you?

Comment: @Terry : can you add you answer? I can again start bounty for existing answer. Believe me !!!! Waiting for your answer....

Comment: I would appreciate another answer, but if you don't have an access to iis server ?

Comment: @abcdefhi sure. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/search-engine-optimization-toolkit. No point answering because this is exactly what bigfllahull posted.

Answer (score 3):

If this is simply for SEO, the easiest solution and the one I would use is to use url rewrite (assuming you are hosting on IIS) or mod rewrite (if you are hosting on Apache) to enforce lower case urls and leave posts as they are.

With IIS it's as simple as installing url rewrite from the web platform installer, hit add rule and select "enforce lowercase URLs". Easy.

If you upgrade to mvc4 and really want lowercase posts, there is a property `LowercaseUrls` which you can set to true when you register the routes. But again - I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, I don't think `Application_BeginRequest` is the way to go. MVC provides much better options to handle such requirements.

It could also be achieved using IIS `Url Rewrite` module (with `Web.config` configuration), but i assume you prefer a more programmatic approach.

Try with `ActionFilter` instead:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnforceLowercaseUrlAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private bool _redirect;

    public EnforceLowercaseUrlAttribute(bool redirect = true)
    {
        this._redirect = redirect;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var path = request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        var containsUpperCase = path.Any(char.IsUpper);

        if (!containsUpperCase || request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() != "GET")
            return;

        if (this._redirect)
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(path.ToLowerInvariant(), true);

        filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
}
```

Then either apply it to a Controller/Action:

```
[EnforceLowercaseUrl]
public ActionResult Index()
{
     ....
}
```

or register it globally in your `Global.asax`:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new EnforceLowercaseUrlAttribute());
```

Comment: lol why you using true twice ? It's elogical and individual per action or a controller.  And too much code.

Comment: By mistake, i thought i defaulted it to false. fixed.

Comment: You are always returning a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it, I create a custom route. This also makes helpers such as `Html.ActionLink` create manipulated routes too.

First I extend `Route` with a custom object (lets say `LowerCaseRoute`) and override the `GetVirtualPath` method like this:

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    if (path != null)
    {
        // you could do lots more here, like replacing odd characters with - etc.
        path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath.ToLower();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Then I create a custom helper to map this route like this:

```
public static LowerCaseRoute MapLowerCaseRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
{
    var route = new LowerCaseRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler());
    route.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults);
    route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
    route.DataTokens.Add("RouteName", name);
    routes.Add(name, route);
    return route;
}
```

This way you can create a route in your `global.asax` like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapLowerCaseRoute("routeName", "baseurl/someother/{param}", { controller = "Controller", param = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

This keeps everything tidy and obvious inside the project and gives you more options to manipulate your routes.